# pagebackref in revtex4 with multiple references

Tags: hyperref, revtex

MacTEX-2014, Mac OS 10.9.5 -- when I use the code below to add back reference links in the list of references (with pagebackref in revtex4) only the links of first and the last reference appear: I get a link on the right of "aaa" and one on the right of "ddd" but nothing on the right of "bbb" and "ccc".
How can I get the links on all the references?

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{1,2,3,4}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1} aaa

\bibitem{2} bbb

\bibitem{3} ccc

\bibitem{4} ddd

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Citations here are handled by the `natbib` package which the document class loads with the `sort&compress` option.  The compression part means that the list `1,2,3,4` gets reduced to `1--4` and in the process the back references to the intermediate items are not created.

One way around this is to switch of the compression by issuing

```
\makeatletter\def\NAT@cmprs{\z@}\makeatother
```

after the package is loaded.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{revtex4}

\makeatletter\def\NAT@cmprs{\z@}\makeatother

\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{1,2,3,4}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1} aaa

\bibitem{2} bbb

\bibitem{3} ccc

\bibitem{4} ddd

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to have both the compression and the back references. Is it possible in some way?

Comment: It involves changing the hyperref/backref interface to natbib, which is not straightforward.  Maybe someone else is brave enough to try that.